# Virtualbox Ubuntu pygame.display.set_mode acts differently in interactive python than when interpreting file

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, pygame, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu inside virtual box (the host os is Windows 7). I am using python 2.7. The following code behaves strangely in various situations:

```
def set_screen():
    global screen
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))

def set_tk():
    global root
    global embed
    global tkwin
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_title("OpenBox")
    embed = tk.Frame(root, width = 600, height = 600)
    embed.pack(side=LEFT)
    windowid = embed.winfo_id()
    tkwin = tk.Frame(root, width = 200, height = 600)
    tkwin.pack(side=RIGHT)
    os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(windowid)
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        if sys.argv[1] == "-f":
            root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

set_tk()
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()
set_screen()
```

This is meant to create a tkinter window with a pygame display embedded into it. This is some of the various behaviours I have come across:

### Windows

On windows, the code works fine. A tkinter frame is opened with an embedded pygame display, just as intended.

### VirtualBox Ubuntu interpreting file

On Ubuntu, when I run the program file (typing "python "), the program does not work, with this error being triggered upon calling pygame.display.set_mode (the error is not raised if I do not set the os environ that embeds the pygame window into tkinter):

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GetWindowAttributes)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x1600004
  Serial number of failed request:  53
  Current serial number in output stream:  54
```

### VirtualBox Ubuntu interactive python

I can enter the very same code that did not work when typing "python script.py" and enter it into interactive python and the code will work. The first main difference between interactive python and running python on a file is timing, so I first tried adding a time.sleep() before I call display.set_mode, but this made no difference. The other main difference is that it handles exceptions without halting the program, so I also tried try and except to test for this and it did not solve the problem. I also can't just run the entire program in interactive python (perhaps feeding it through pexpect or subprocess handles on stdin and stdout) because there are also tkinter threads that maintain a gui sidebar to my pygame display, and they do not work in interactive python.

### VirtualBox Ubuntu exec

I also tried using exec to call display.set_mode, hoping this execution environment may be different. However, calling exec set_mode yields identical results to just calling set_mode, meaning it works in interactive python, but not when reading a file.

### VirtualBox Ubuntu interactive python functions

The code also behaves differently within functions. In interactive python, running all of this code within a function will make it fail to work. When I experimented what code worked and didn't work inside a function, I found that the code that must be entered outside of a function was pygame.display.set_mode. Curiously, when I put display.set_mode alone in a single function without other code, it worked. All of the above situations throw errors when python is reading the code from a file.

---

I also tried defining all the display information interactively and then pickling it for my main program to load and access. Since pygame.surface objects cannot be pickled, however, this did not work.

---

Why would this code work in some environments but not in others? Is there a way to make this code succeed in Virtualbox Ubuntu?

Comment: I have a similar setup. If you provide me with a minumum working example, I'd be happy to give it a try here.

Comment: It seems you don't have hardware video acceleration enabled. Try this: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=57160

Comment: I'll post some more of the pertinent code, though I can't post the entire program it is very long

Comment: Also, I did try installing the guest additions. They didn't make any difference.

Comment: I looked at the virtualbox forum and executed the command they suggested, ("glxinfo | grep OpenGL") but it didn't stop the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter needs `mainloop()` to work.
Without `mainloop()` Tkinter ends work at once.

Windows and Interactive Python probably don't bother this or they use own mainloop to keep Tkinter running.

There is another problem: `mainloop()` keeps Tkinter working but it doesn't allow to run any line below `mainloop()` (before `mainloop()` (and Tkinter) ends work). So I use `after()` to run `set_screen()` 100 ms later - when `mainloop()` will be working.

Tested on (non-virtual) Linux Mint 16 (base on Ubuntu) with Python 2.7.5

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os

def set_screen():
    global screen

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), screen_rect.center, 50 )
    pygame.display.flip()


def set_tk():
    global root
    global embed
    global tkwin
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_title("OpenBox")
    embed = tk.Frame(root, width = 600, height = 600)
    embed.pack(side=LEFT)
    windowid = embed.winfo_id()
    tkwin = tk.Frame(root, width = 200, height = 600)
    tkwin.pack(side=RIGHT)
    os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(windowid)
    #~ if sys.platform == "win32":
        #~ os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
    #~ if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        #~ if sys.argv[1] == "-f":
            #~ root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)         
    root.after(100,set_screen)
    root.mainloop()

set_tk()
```

Comment: The code you gave me does work. However, I am actually using root.update() in a while loop later in the program. However, I tried calling root.update after doing this, using root.after, and it worked. I'm not sure why, but I think using root.after keeps tkinter running long eneough for the program to start calling the main loop.